# Can i use different implementation of a dependency in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project using gradle and i created and i want to build the project for two different frameworks (A and B).
I created an interface that i use in my project as an abstraction of the frameworks and then created two dependencies who are implementations of the interface in the different frameworks
(ImplA et ImplB)

How can i configure Gradle to build two jars where one will use ImpLA and the other ImplB from one code base using the interface ?